# add value to existing value in sql table by vb

Tags: sql, vb6

```
iD     NAME
1      ALEX
2      SAM   
3      MARK
```

The above is table i need code in vb to add value to existing value same as

```
ID     Name
1      ALEX,nancy
2      SAM
3      MARK, SUZAN
```

Comment: Are you asking about SQL or VB?

Answer (score 1):

How about just do it in SQL

```sql
UPDATE Table1
   SET Name = Name + ',' + 'Nancy'
 WHERE id = 1;

UPDATE Table1
   SET Name = Name + ',' + 'Suzan'
 WHERE id = 3;
```

**[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/48f4e/1)**